# How to use powershell count operator's turning number in if statement?

Tags: powershell

I want to count running process and I want to use powershell count operator's turning number in if statement, which one is variable there? i am newbie on ps, For examplae 6 process should be run, i want to use like that

```
if ( Process number -lt 6) {
    $msgBody = "It is not working" [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show($msgBody)
}
```

I tried like that but not worked

```
function numInstances([string]$process)
{
    @(Get-Process $process -ErrorAction 0).Count
}

numInstances notepad
if ($process -lt 3)
{
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationCore,PresentationFramework
    $msgBody = "Notepad is Not Working"
    [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show($msgBody)
}
```

Comment: the question is not enterally clear, I think you might be looking for: `if ((numInstances notepad) -lt 3) { ....` ?

Comment: or perhaps assign `$process = numInstances notepad` (but perhaps a better name like `$processCount` or some such

Answer (score 0):

As implied by the comments:

- You must call your `numInstances` function and uses *its output* (return value).
- In order for the function call to participate in an *expression* (comparison with `-lt`), you must enclose it in `(...)`, the [grouping operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#grouping-operator--)

```bash
if ((numInstances notepad) -lt 3) {
    $msgBody = "Notepad is Not Working"
    [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show($msgBody)
}
```

Given the simplicity of the function, you could use the only call in its body *directly*:

```bash
if ((Get-Process notepad).Count -lt 3) {
    $msgBody = "Notepad is Not Working"
    [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show($msgBody)
}
```

Either way, you may want to add `-ErrorAction Ignore` to the `Get-Process` call to avoid errors in case there happen to be *no* Notepad processes running.

---

As for **what you tried**:

You seem to have two misconceptions:

- That `@(Get-Process $process -ErrorAction 0).Count` stores the value of the `.Count` *property* in the `$process` variable.

  - Instead, the property value is *output*, to the success [output stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Output_Streams), allowing the caller to operate on it, such as using it in a comparison operation, as shown above.
- That the function-local `$process` variable will be visible to the *caller*.

  - Callers do *not* see variables created inside a function, because functions (by default) run in a *child scope* - see the conceptual [about_Scopes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Scopes) help topic.

Comment: Glad to hear it helped, @matrix. Note that you can help future readers by clearly signaling which answer, if any, solved your problem, namely by [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/248777) it.